# Does anyone have a manual or spec regarding an NEC JAPAN D78P0308GF

Tags: microcontroller, specifications

As the headline states.

It seems to be hard to get! The uC is in a Siemens Landsi & Gyr Dialog.
Power measurment equipment 3-phase ZMD120AMer53

[image]

Comment: What do you need it for? A microcontroller's datasheet doesn't tell you anything about the program it runs, for instance, so the datasheet won't make you any wiser about the operation of the meter.

Comment: :) No but a datasheet can tell me how it is connected to "the outside world". The datasheet will make me wiser, because if I understand the electric connections and the other circuits I understand their functions. In the terms of programming, I more or less already understands it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a direct link to the microcontroller: http://documentation.renesas.com/doc/DocumentServer/U11377EJ3V0UD00.pdf